# Syntax Highlighting for irb with SublimeREPL

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, irb

I am using Sublime Text 2 as a text editor, with SublimeREPL to get a Ruby REPL. The problem is that irb likes to give output like:

```
irb(main):008:0> hello
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object
    from (irb):8
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

which messes up syntax highlighting (because of the extra ' at the end). The only "solution" I could come up with was to cause *another* error so the 's match (or turn off syntax highlighting altogether, which would defeat the point of bringing the REPL to ST in the first place).

While only a minor one, it is nevertheless an annoyance. Does anyone here know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to fix this would be to create a IRB Console.tmLanguage which would tokenize and parse irb's output correctly.

As for the quick fix/workaround, evaluating this will rebalance '

```
irb(main):015:0> 0 #'
```